# Error sending Post request ASP.Net Using AJAX & JavaScript (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax

I am having issues sending a Post request ASP.Net using AJAX and JavaScript. My intentions are to send multiple values to a database and insert them. I have an html page with the following functions calling ASP request using AJAX.

.html file:

```
// Builds AJAX request and sends it to ASP page
function sendInfo(x,y,z){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged; 
    xmlhttp.open("POST","Update.asp",true);
    xmlhttp.send("addy="+encodeURIComponent(x)+
                  "&lat="+encodeURIComponent(y)+
                  "&lng="+encodeURIComponent(z));
}

// Checks the ready state of the sent response
function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="Error with ready state: " + xmlhttp.readyState + " and status: " + xmlhttp.status;
    }
}
```

Here is my .asp file:

```
<% 
    conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection"); 
    conn.Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" +  Server.MapPath("Project.mdb"));

    var addy=Request.Form("addy");
    var lat=Request.Form("lat");
    var lng=Request.Form("lng");

    var sql="INSERT INTO Location_Info (Address,Latitude,Longitude)"
    sql= sql + " VALUES "
    sql= sql + "('" + addy + "',"
    sql= sql + "'" + lat + "',"
    sql= sql + "'" + lng + "')"

    rs = conn.Execute(sql);
    Response.Write("Your record has been placed into the database.");

    rs.Close();
    conn.Close();
%>
```

Whenever I run my page and enter the proper information to be sent, it only returns the else case of "Error with ready state: 4 and status: 500". This status of 500 is a general error and I am unsure of how to debug my program, as I have even tried commenting everything in the .asp file and only having 'Response.Write("text");' code, but to no avail, still status:500 error.

If someone can help me with what I am doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If Response.Write("text"); gives you status 500 then there is something misconfigured in your server. Maybe asp configuration or more probable permissions issue.

Comment: That could very well be the issue, any advice on how to change the configuration to allow asp?